# What area of mathematics involves "anomalous" mirror image illusions?

Tags: geometry

The *Symmetry* journal article ["Anomalous Mirror Symmetry Generated by Optical Illusion"](http://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/8/4/21/htm) by Kokichi Sugihara discusses objects such as the one shown here:

[image]

(Image taken from article.)

I want to understand this type of math, but my math level is only algebra. 
What area of math do I need to understand in order to fully understand this author's work?

Comment: A course on group theory will help you to discover symmetries, though I don't think the author used any subjects directly related to groups

Comment: I agree with @James, this isn't really relevant to somewhere like Maths Stack Exchange, but is pretty interesting all the same! I must say, though, I do not know what he means by "the object does not obey the law of optical physics". Y'know, that *one law* in optics. You don't really need any major mathematics to understand what he is saying. Just read through it carefully, with a notepad, and think about it.

Comment: This is a reasonable question and doesn't deserve the disapproval it's receiving.

Comment: FYI: YouTuber "Captain Disillusion" did a video about a similar illusion (["Ambiguous Cylinders"](https://youtu.be/yupxceBjDa0)), and even posted a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/95E3pBuJBO8) about how he created a virtual version of such a cylinder in the Blender app. He mentions that the Make Anything channel created 3D-printed models of the things, but I haven't looked for those videos. (Of course, there's no hard math in the CD video; the journal paper OP references covers that kind of thing. Still, seeing such an object being created can be enlightening.)

Answer (score 1):

At first glance this mostly looked like [analytic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_geometry).

There is a bit of [calculus of several variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_of_several_real_variables#Calculus) and [geometrical optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_optics).

I would need to look at the references too to give a better answer.

Comment: Why I need to fully understand the mathematics is so I can write programs to make my own similar illusions